# Singed apk doesn't show the google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am implementing the google map in my application and every time I run it through source code runs correctly means google map appears but when run through signed apk it doesn't show the google map. I make the singed apk several times but the problem is still there. Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you generate a `New API Key` with your own `Sign Certificate`?

Comment: No. ok i am going to try it

Answer (score 1):

You have to change SHA in Google play console.

### Generate new SHA from your Keystore file(which you have used to generate signed apk) & add it on Google play console with package name.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

after that change Google map key in your code.

create new signed APK, install in device check Google map.

Comment: can I get it like window->preferences->android->build->SHA1 fingerprint ?

Comment: no, that SHA will be used for development not for relase, thats why you have to generate new SHA from android keystore file. follow my answer

Comment: the following command i run in my command prompt as you mentioned, the sha1 key i got through this method is same as i got thorugh window->preferences->android->build->sha1

Comment: c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\Dell\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android

Comment: have u every release apk on play store?

Comment: you must have to use that keystore(to generate SHA) which you have used to generate signed apk.

Comment: actually the problem with map was there when i uploaded the app for the first time but i didn't notice it that time. Now i come to know about it through client

Comment: what i am trying to say: you have to get SHA from keystore file, use that SHA to generate Google map v2 Key. got it now?

Comment: ok the problem has been solved through my-release-key command. Thanks for your time